# A problem with definitions of rotation/reflection matrix/operator

Tags: geometry, matrices

I am a math undergraduate student taking a course called "Geometry
and symmetry" and I have something I don't understand with the definition
the lecture gave in class.

**Definition:** $T\,:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called
a **linear rotation operator** if there exist an orthonormal
basis $B$ s.t $$\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\\
 &  & 1\\
 &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$.

**Definition:** $T\,:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called
a **linear reflection operator** if there exist an orthonormal
basis $B$ s.t $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & .\\
 &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$.

The definitions for matrix $P$ are that a matrix is called **linear reflection matrix** if there is an orthogonal matrix
$P$ s.t $P^{-1}AP$ is in one of the above forms, accordingly.

Later on, there is a theorem that says that is $T\,:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
is orthogonal then there exist an orthonormal basis $B$ s.t $$[T]_{B}=\begin{pmatrix}R_{\theta_{1}}\\
 & R_{\theta_{2}}\\
 &  & .\\
 &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  & R_{\theta_{k}}\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & -1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & -1
\end{pmatrix};R_{\theta}:=\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

My question is: if $T$ is orthogonal then if $A$ is a matrix s.t
$Tv=Av$ then $A$ is orthogonal hence $|A|=1$ or $|A|=-1$. in the
first case I learned that by $A$ is a linear rotation matrix, in
the second case I learned that $A$ is **linear reflection
operator**, so I deduce that there is an orthonormal basis in which
$A$ have the form of the two matrix above - i.e rotating around some
$2$ dimensional space fixing the other $n-2$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
or rotating around some vector fixing the other $n-1$ subspace of
$\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

It seems that the matrix in the theorem is very different than the
first two matrix in the question since it has $k$ (that can be $>1$)
rotations, and it can reflects around more then $1$ vector...

Can someone please explain whats going on here? I expected the theorem
to be the $[T]_{B}$ is one of the first two matrices in the question,
instead I have in front of me a strange looking matrix that I can
not classify as a rotation or a reflection matrix, so where in my
reasoning I am wrong (I determined that $[T]_{B}$ is the first matrix
in the question if $A$ above have det $1$ and the second if $A$
have det -1) ?

Comment: You can use `\ddots` to get three dots in a diagonal, like so: $\ddots$ You should also use `\cos` and `\sin` to write $\cos\theta$ instead of $cos\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from the mistaken belief that *every* orthogonal matrix with positive determinant is what you call a "linear rotation operator". [That happens to be true in three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem), but not more. However, every orthogonal matrix with positive determinant is a *composition* of such linear rotation operators, also known as [simple rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planes_of_rotation). So you can think of the latter as the set of "atomic" rotations that all other rotations are composed of.